# Finding minimum allowed third side of a triangle

Tags: c++, arrays, geometry

I have an array of integers `A`, denoting the length of side of triangle. I need to find the minimum length of the third possible if any two sides are taken from the array as the other 2 sides.

Now I know that if the third side be `c` and other two sides be `a` and `b(a>b)` minimum side possible is `c>a-b` or `c=a-b+1`.

I sorted the array and took consecutive difference to find the side possible. However I'm getting wrong answer. My code is as follows :

```
int n;
cin>>n; // stores length of sides of triangle
int a[n];        
sort(a,a+n);
   unsigned long long int min2 = numeric_limits<double>::infinity();  
   for(long long i=0;i<n-1;i++)
   {
      if ((a[i+1] - a[i] +1 ) <= min2)
        min2 = a[i+1] - a[i] +1;
   }

cout<<min2;
```

For eg - A = [2 2 2] so the minimum third will be 1. It is correct according to me but fails on a test case unknown to me.

Where am I doing wrong ? I think the mistake is in the `+1` in the if condition. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] and tell us what the input and output is together with the expected output.

Comment: @tobi303 That's the problem. I don't know where it is going wrong because neither do I know the input nor the expected output.

Comment: huh? where is the input coming from? If you dont know the answer, then your approach is wrong. You should first take pen and paper or do some [reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle) only when you know how to solve it on paper it makes sense to start writing code.

Comment: The input is generated online by tester. And since I don't know the input, I don't know what answer are they expecting. I solved the problem using pen and paper first, then I came with this code for minimum length of third side. I think the problem may be in `+1` part in if condition and the statement below it. Should I increment the minimum value of `a-b` at last or is it fine increasing it in loop?

Comment: The minimum height of any side will be `1`. And I just want to find the mistake which I have been stuck on for weeks.

Comment: I have tried all test cases possible. All ranges of height, even with height of all sides being same. The solution is failing on 1 test case only.

Comment: Did you read my first comment? The code you show here does not provide any answer, it does not even compile. If you want others to diagnose the problem you have to give them the possibility to reproduce it

Comment: `cin << n; int a[n];` is not allowed.

Comment: @tobi303 `cin>>n; int a[n]` is allowed as I always use this.

Comment: it is a compiler extension of gcc I think, but it isnt standard c++.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem: The sum of lengths of any two sides of a triangle is greater than the length of the third side.

> if u select 8 and 13 has two sides then minimum length for third side is 6 and maximum would b 20

Comment: if you call it theorem you should either give a proof or reference one ;)

Comment: your example isnt correct. If two sides are 8 and 13 then minimum of third is 5 not 6 and maximum is 21 not 20

Comment: @tobi303 We are only looking for non degenerate triangle so equality doesn't hold there.

Comment: @sammy you didnt mention that in the question and the answer on its own is just wrong (without that additional constraint)